# How to change the backslashes from the main directory?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I installed a package (FsLab), i load it like this:

```
#load "packages\FsLab\FsLab.fsx"
```

But then i get an error

```
Could not load file C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Tutorial1\packages/<packagename>' because it does not exist or is inaccessible
```

Which is understandable, since the main directory contains backward slashes and the directory to the package contains forward slashes. I have checked in the files of the package and like i guessed it, it contains sub packages that are forward slashed

How to fix this this so that the slashes of the main directory are forward?

Comment: F# and Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 3):

It is fixed by changing the load file:

```
#load @"..\packages\FsLab.1.0.2\FsLab.fsx"
```

The @ sign from the microsoft page:

> When placed before a string literal, indicates that the string is to
>   be interpreted verbatim, with no interpretation of escape characters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/